# PHP Perl combination

Tags: php

I have developed an interface that takes data from the users. I need to take this data to a perl script that I have already written. Now the problem is that I am not able to figure out how to call the Perl script automatically from the PHP interface. 
I don't have enough experience with PHP, so have no clue how to internally call the Perl script.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [`exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), but take a look at the left hand sidebar in case some other function from that family is more suitable.